# Intuitive meaning of Double Commutant Theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, oa.operator-algebras

Is there any intuitive explanation of the Double Commutant Theorem for Von Neumann Algebras? By intuitive I mean in terms of Quantum Mechanics. For example, duality of states and observables in the case of the Gelfand-Naimark Theorem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_bicommutant_theorem

Comment: May be worth to add link to theorem or say what is it about .... then you will get my + 1 :)

Comment: @a.chernov done!

Comment: It seems that what you want (as supplied by Nik Weaver) is an intuitive *description* rather than an intuitive *explanation*. I zmean, what is an intuiive explanation of something being WOT-closed?

Comment: @YemonChoi that there is a fair number elements in the topology for a particular purpose?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, here's an explanation in terms of quantum mechanics. Let ${\cal A}$ be a family of observables, modeled as self-adjoint operators on some Hilbert space, and let ${\cal U}$ be the group of all unitary transformations that leave every observable in ${\cal A}$ invariant. You can consider ${\cal U}$ to be a kind of symmetry group. Mathematically it is the set of unitaries in the first commutant ${\cal A}'$ of ${\cal A}$, and the set of all observables left invariant by ${\cal U}$ is the double commutant of ${\cal A}$. So the double commutant theorem says that the set of all observables left invariant by every transformation that leaves every observable in ${\cal A}$ invariant, is the self-adjoint part of the von Neumann algebra generated by ${\cal A}$.

Comment: This is a nice description, but I don't really see how it's an *explanation*...

Comment: How about "an explanation of the intuitive meaning"?

Answer (score -2):

Weak closure is more universal than norm closure. Commutative C* algebra is an algebra of continuous functions on spectrum, which could be any compact space. Von Neumann algebras deal with measure, and measure space is universal - the interval [0,1] with Lebesgue measure (provided measure of a point equals to 0).
Check the V.A.Rokhlin theorem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_probability_space